# How do I access this type of C++ shared memory in a C# application?

Tags: c#, c++, shared-memory

I have some code from another programmer that uses/creates shared memory in what I think is the page file.  The code being used is:

```
HANDLE hMapObject;
HWND hWnd;
float *MapView;
float MapScale[10];
BOOL MapError, MapViewError;
DWORD LastMapError; // shared memory file init
hMapObject = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, "GInterface");
if (!hMapObject)
{
    hMapObject = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof (MapScale), "GInterface");
    if (!hMapObject)
    {
        MapError = true;
        LastMapError = GetLastError();
    }
}
MapView = (float*)MapViewOfFile(hMapObject, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
if (!MapView)
{
    MapViewError = true;
    LastMapError = GetLastError();
}
```

I've looked at the shared memory stuff for C# but it doesn't seem to relate to what I have here in any way. My C# program only needs to read from the shared memory, not write to it if  that helps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not the page file, it's a memory mapped file.  A file that exists in memory only.

To access that shared memory, you would need to pinvoke MapViewOfFile of pass in the handle that CreateFileMapping returned in the C++ code.  E.g. somehow you need to know that handle.

Comment: If you google "CreateFileMapping" and "MapViewOfFile" it will lead you to the MSDN documentation for those Windows API functions, as they are part of the Windows API.

Comment: You can't find it in C# by the name "GInterface"?

Comment: Correction to my comment, the Named file is first opened with OpenFileMapping.  If that fails, it does not exist, so it creates the shared memory mapped file with CreateFileMapping giving it a name of GInterface.

So in c# you will need to pinvoke OpenFileMapping, pass in the File_Map_all_access, false, and GInterface.

If it's been created already it should succeed.

Comment: Here is a link to pinvoke for OpenFileMapping: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/OpenFileMapping.html

Comment: @Ryios there are [.NET APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) for this, no need for P/Invoke.

Comment: Yeah, I see them, they added them in .Net 4.. I haven't done this since prior to .Net 4

Comment: OpenFileMapping doesn't exist in C#...I think you're thinking backwards...the above posted code works just fine, I just need to be able to do the same in C#...I only have access to the MemoryMappedFiles in System.IO, but I don't know how to relate it by the same name in C#.

Comment: Anything in c++ you can do in C#, it just requires PInvokes (dllimport) and marshalling, and a whole lot of tediousness.. However you should be able to use the code I posted below.

Comment: @Ryios: [CreateFileMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537.aspx): *"hFile: If hFile is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, [...] CreateFileMapping creates a file mapping object of a specified size that is **backed by the system paging file** instead of by a file in the file system."*

Comment: It's backed by the page file, but it means "It's in memory" it's only going to hit the page file if it get's paged.  Both technically correct.  My bad for not seeing that in the documentation though.

Comment: @Ryios: How does the API specification make your comment (*"a file that exists in memory only"*) correct? That is technically incorrect. You **always** have to specify a file backing store.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/01/10398358.aspx

Comment: I opened my original comment incorrectly, and that is in deed incorrect, my apologies.  All I'm trying to get accross is "backed by the page file" does not necessarily mean it will be in the page file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to open the memory mapped file in c# with

```
var mappedFile = System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(MemoryMappedFileRights.Read, "GInterface");

using (Stream view = mappedFile.CreateViewStream())
{
    //read the stream here.
}
```

Comment: This looks good...The values are usually access in C++ as MapView[0] or MapView[2] etc...the memory is a float array with 10 items in it.  How do I construct my stream viewer to read that array properly? I've gotten down to the binaryreader, but when I try to read I get errors.  I'm still not sure how to pull the actual values.

Comment: @Robbie P. When you call CreateViewStream() specify the size allocated by the memory mapped file as well as the access type (e.g. CreateViewStream(0, sizeof(float) * 10, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read);

Comment: @alexm do I still need a BinaryReader or can I access the stream in another way?  Is the stream an array of floats?

Answer (score 0):

C# Extensions claims it now supports the root namespace property.

https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2675

If you look at the changelog here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/kreativ-software.csharpextensions/changelog

As of version [1.3.5] on 2020-07-03, they added RootNamespace detection which respects the root namespace in the project file.

So now when you use C# Extensions to do stuff, it'll use whatever is in the RootNamespace field in the csproj file.  Like adding new classes, enums, etc etc.

Note that the fix is in "C# Extensions" which is not the same extension as the c# omnisharp extension for vs code.  It's this one:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kreativ-software.csharpextensions